# How can I plot a counter in order?

Tags: python, plot, count, bar-chart, counter

I have a Python Counter that stores tuple keys and int values and looks something like this:

```
Counter({(0,): 31118, (160,): 7931, (229,): 7183, (225,): 5668, (48,): 5667, ... , (171,): 19})
```

The items inside are in descending order of their values and I am trying to plot them the same way.

I tried using plt.bar while only using the first 10 values (it is in the same random order when using the full set):

```
keylist = list()

for key in countersum.keys():
    keylist.append(str(key))

plt.bar(keylist[:10], list(countersum.values())[:10])
plt.show()
```

Which gives me the following diagram:
[image]

The question is why is it not ordered and how can I make it so it plots in descending order to their values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, You need first sort `dict` base on values then plot them like below:

```
>>> dct = {(171,): 19, (0,): 31118, (225,): 5668, (160,): 7931, (48,): 5667, (229,): 7183}

>>> srt_dct = dict(sorted(dct.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))

>>> srt_dct
{(0,): 31118,
 (160,): 7931,
 (229,): 7183,
 (225,): 5668,
 (48,): 5667,
 (171,): 19}
```